# Dynamically Pass List item parameter using pnp js

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, pnpjs, react-webpart

I have created SPFx web part using React JS framework. I am reading the data from the CSV file and adding item to SharePoint list using `inBatch` in PnP JS.

I was able to add the item to SharePoint list by passing the parameter name with static value. But I have a requirement of adding the column with it's value dynamically.

Below is the sample to add item with column value like below.

```
var ItemArray = [];
ItemArray.push(pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle('listdisplayname').items.inBatch(batch).add({
    Title : "Title"
}));

Promise.all(ItemArray).then(function() {
    console.log("Item Added successfully!!");
});

batch.execute();
```

Please let me know, if there is any way to pass parameter dynamically.

Example:

```
var ItemArray = [];
var body = "Title : dynamic value"

ItemArray.push(pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle('listdisplayname').items.inBatch(batch).add({
    body
}));

Promise.all(ItemArray).then(function() {
    console.log("Item Added successfully!!");
});

batch.execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using something like below:

```
var ItemArray = [];

var internalNameOfTitleCol = "Title"
var titleColValue = "Here is a dynamic value for list item Title";
var body = {};
body[internalNameOfTitleCol] = titleColValue;

ItemArray.push(pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle('listdisplayname').items.inBatch(batch).add(body));

Promise.all(ItemArray).then(function() {
    console.log("Item Added successfully!!");
});

batch.execute();
```

**Note**: Make sure you are using correct [internal names](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/) of your SharePoint Columns.

**Update from comments**:

Try like below:

```
var body = {};
for(var l = 0; l < SPColumnName.length; l++){
    body[SPInternalName[l]] = CSVColumnsVal[[l]];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the update but I am column name (i.e. "Title") is also dynamic.


for(var l = 0; l < SPColumnName.length; l++){

                  body += SPInternalName[l] + " : " + CSVColumnsVal[[l]] + ",";
                }

Comment: Welcome. Please check the updated answer. This will solve your issue.

Comment: I have tried the above approach. It is created array but while adding the item it is still throwing the error like below.


Uncaught (in promise) ProcessHttpClientResponseException: Error making HttpClient request in queryable: [400] Bad Request

Comment: Well, that issue is something related to your PnP JS call. For this check the documentation [here](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/items/#add-multiple-items). Is there any reason you are using Promises?

Comment: My PnP JS call is working fine if I hard coded add the column name and it's value.
I have used Promises to add bulk items in list

Comment: I am now able to add the item. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: Great, I am glad it worked for you. please [upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you.